# Can I view my MySql query from Symfony's debug toolbar when my response is JSON?

Tags: symfony

When the output is just a JSON response, the debug toolbar doesn't show up. It'd be awfully nice to see what the actual query was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search for your latest requested page and get detailed info about it.
Just visit following link, and you'll see search form there.

```
http://yoursite.com/app_dev.php/_profiler/
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize the debug info about executed queries was limited to Doctrine queries.